# How can I force mySQL database to store this special character: ╠?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, phpmyadmin, special-characters

I am inserting this variable into the mySQL database with php:

```
$name="Ele ╠phant";


 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db -> exec("set names utf8");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO data (name) values(?) ";
 $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array($name));
```

I wish that it is exactly stored like this (`Ele ╠phant`) in the database.
But via phpMyadmin I see that it is not stored like this:

```
Ele?phant
```

My collation is `utf8_general_ci`.

I tested another method:

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db -> exec("set names utf8mb4");

 $sql = "INSERT INTO data (name) values(?) ";
 $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute(array($name));
```

And in phpMyadmin I set the collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci` but still it stores `Ele?phant`

Comment: are you sure that the code is storing  `Ele?phant` ???  you are using `$pdo` as a connection resource while you have stored your connection on `$db` !! pay attention to your connection otherwise utf8_general_ci should work with `╠` this character

Comment: Replace double quotes with single quotes around sql statement and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of

`$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
 $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
 $db -> exec("set names utf8");`

do this 1 line: 
`$db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";port=8889;dbname=".DBNAME.';charset=utf8mb4', DBUSER, DBPASS,array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`
 
also note how i changed it from `utf8` to `utf8mb4`.

quote `My collation is utf8_general_ci.` - best guess, that's your problem right there (along with wrong connection characterset). see, mysql's `utf8` is not the real utf8, but a retardedly-named subset, while the real utf8 is named `utf8mb4` in MySQL. a subset that probably doesn't support the `╠` character. run `utf8mb4` / `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` all the way through, and you shouldn't get this problem. furthermore, if in the future, you'd like MySQL to throw an error instead of corrupting your data when the data can't be inserted, enable the STRICT_ALL_TABLES sql_mode. (then you would get an exception, instead of mysql storing a corrupted version of your string)

(this is also true for MariaDB, which inherited this brain-damage from the MySQL source code it was forked from)

Comment: Thank you, I will test it now. What do you mean by  `run utf8mb4 / utf8mb4_unicode_ci all the way through`

Comment: @Jarla i mean, when you connect, explicitly use the `utf8mb4` characterset, and when you choose collation for a text type, always use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` - and when you serve the html, specify `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf8` in the http headers

Comment: I changed my collation to`utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and also changed my database connection the way you suggested. But still it is stored `Ele?phant` Just cannot get it work :'-(

Comment: @Jarla now that is weird. what does this code give you? https://pastebin.com/qfrJmF4w

Comment: the result of your code is: `array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["input"]=>
    string(13) "Ele ╠ phant"
  }
}`

Comment: Ok, I could insert now the word Ele ╠ phant into the mySQL database! One big step forward. Unfortunately still not into my destination table... I will check, why it is not working there and let you know, if I find out

Comment: It is working now! I needed to write `$db->` instead of `$pdo->`